# VBA "Argument Not Optional" - unsure how to declare variables

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to write a VBA macro that assigns values to specific cells by calculating the average of the cells directly above and below it. I am running it by selecting the Macros button on the Developer toolbar, then I have to type in the name of my function (it doesn't appear on the list) "interpprob" and select run. I then get a popup that states "Argument is not optional." I'm not quite sure what the problem is. The full macro is below. "tstep" is meant to be an array of the set of rows that need some cell values changed.

```
Function interpprob(f As Integer, d As Integer, spec As String, tstep As Long, above As Long, below As Long, i As Integer, j As Integer)

f = 41
d = 441
spec = ETHA

tstep(0) = f
tstep(1) = f + d
tstep(2) = f + 2 * d
tstep(3) = f + 5 * d

For i = 0 To 4
    For j = 52 To 57
        above = Cells(tstep(i) - 1, j).Value
        below = Cells(tstep(i) + 1, j).Value
        Sheets(spec).Cells(tstep(i), j).Value = (above + below) / 2
    Next j
Next i

End Function
```

Thanks,
BL Roo

Comment: Make sure you are calling `interpprob` with all 8 arguments.

Comment: How would that be done? Just by typing "interpprob(f, d, spec, tstep, above, below, i, j)"?

Comment: you want actual values (arguments) in place of those 8 parameters. Do you have an idea what values you are going to put to `f`, `d`, `spec`, etc?

Comment: I thought I could just define those within the macro (as I currently have)?

Comment: If you are going to assign specific values to variables within the procedure (and it should be a `Sub`, not a `Function`, because you aren't returning a value) then don't bother passing the variables as parameters.

Comment: Also note that (1) You haven't assigned a value to the variable `ETHA` (perhaps that was meant to be `"ETHA"`) (2) You haven't dimensioned the size of the `tstep` array (3) You haven't assigned a value to `tstep(4)` (4) `Cells(tstep(i) - 1, j)` will be referring to a location on the active sheet while `Sheets(spec).Cells(tstep(i), j)` is referring to a location on the sheet defined by the variable `spec`.

Comment: Ah yes, that seems to have worked now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your expectations, change `Function` into `Sub` and remove the parameters.

```
Sub interpprob()

    f = 41
    d = 441
    spec = "ETHA"

    tstep(0) = f
    tstep(1) = f + d
    tstep(2) = f + 2 * d
    tstep(3) = f + 5 * d

    For i = 0 To 3  'Changed from 4 as you do not assign a value to tstep(4)
        For j = 52 To 57
            above = Cells(tstep(i) - 1, j).Value
            below = Cells(tstep(i) + 1, j).Value
            Sheets(spec).Cells(tstep(i), j).Value = (above + below) / 2
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

You can also insert the following declarations just after the `Sub`:

```vb
Dim f As Long
Dim d As Long
Dim spec As String
Dim tstep(0 To 3) As Long
Dim above As Long
Dim below As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
```

It is a practice which pays off when a program grows. It keeps you safe from several kinds of mistakes.

To make this practice mandatory, insert the following directive as first line of the file (just before everything else):

```vb
Option Explicit
```

You can also see that type `Integer` was replaced by `Long` because Integer is too short (–32768 ... +32767) and unpractical for standard use and keeping around both `Integer` and `Long` has no real benefit (and has a performance penalty). Just declare every integer variable as `Long`.

**Credits for suggestions and fixes go to [YowE3K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6535336/yowe3k) and [robinCTS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1961728/robincts).**

Comment: Using `Long` instead of `Integer` is just better practice these days, so I won't worry about it (especially considering that the OP had used `Integer`) - I'll +1 as is.

Comment: I did make a couple of edits because trying to use `tstep(4) - 1` as a row was going to crash out.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions, I believe I have it working now!

Comment: miroxlav & @YowE3K The reason you should ___always___* use `Long` is that it is the default type used by VBA internally for non-floating point numbers. Anytime you use an operator, like `+` for example, on implicit type conversion to `Long` occurs for the operands, the operation takes place, and then the result is converted back to `Long` All these implicit type conversions have a performance impact.    * Unless you have a very,very,*very* special reason to do so. (Such as in an API function declare statement.)

Comment: miroxlav & @BRoo Even better would be to force auto-insertion of the `Option Explicit` statement by checking the `Tools > Options > Editor > Require Variable Declaration` setting in the VBE.